# Induction heating

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, induction

An induction cooktop has a high frequency power source that is applied to a coil. I was wondering if you could take the high frequency electronics on a cooktop and instead of a coil take a 30 or 90 foot long wire and attach to rebar to heat it to a temperature of only about 30 degrees Celsius?

Comment: Most of the heating is due to domain wall motion in the alternating magnetic field. One needs fields that are strong enough.

Comment: @Pieter what you have in mind is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration, but in reality the heating is due to the Joule heating due to Eddy currents https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_heating. As Floris said, ferromagnetic materials have a very tiny skin depth, which means they have a huge impedance and so the Eddy currents are able to heat a lot more than in common metals. With your explanation, any non ferro/ferrimagnetic material shouldn't heat via induction heating, but this is not true.

Comment: @thermomagneticcondensedboson No, of course I am not thinking of refrigeration. No, the skin depth is not very different from non-magnetic metals (this would not give more heating anyway). Most of the heating is due to hysteresis which is due to domain walls that do not move freely.

Comment: @Pieter the skin depth goes like $1/\sqrt(\mu)$, where mu is the magnetic permeability. There's around an order of magnitude difference between the skin depth of Ni (ferromagnetic) and Cu, Ag, Au, and Al. The surface resistance of a stainless steel pan is thus about 85 times greater than that of a copper pan. Then, no wonder that Eddy currents are going to dissipate just as much heat as this ratio, i.e. about 85 times. Unless I am wrong and I cannot assume that I, the (Eddy) current, is the same regardless of the material.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an engineering question - but ultimately, it comes down to two questions:

1. What is the impedance of the system you propose - and is it similar to the impedance that the electronics was designed for?
2. Is the power that the electronics generates sufficient to heat the rebar (that really depends on the mechanism for cooling the rebar... if it's in still air, it probably won't lose a lot of heat when it's only 10°C hotter than the environment).

The key here is that most rebar is ferromagnetic - which means that the skin effect is very strong, and the RF current will flow in just the surface so that the impedance is quite high. But without a lot more details, one cannot say anything with certainty. And once you have the details, you're firmly in engineering territory.

Comment: Well I agree I am in engineering territory. Do you know of an engineer I could contact?

Comment: Have you thought of asking your question on engineering.stackexchange.com? Lots of engineers there last time I looked...

Answer (score -1):

Certainly.  You could do it with a single turn and scan progressively or multi-turn and heat statically.  Face hardening of valve faces or cams on a cam shaft are examples of it being done commercially. In those cases they achieve over 850 C.  In your case you would need only a few watts.  Obviously you must insulate the wire from the bar.

Comment: Do you know of someone who has the engineering know how to confirm if what I wish to do can actually work?